# How to make rectangle visible while selecting a area in image?

Tags: python, opencv

Following code works fine and OCRs selected part of image.
The rectangle for area selection is visible after EVENT_LBUTTONUP while its not during selection.
So, sometimes extra area gets selected.

Any solution to make rectangle visible while selecting the area? .. Tried various combinations of events like LBUTTONDOWN or MOUSEMOVE ...It must be one of these combinations.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

IMAGE_FILE_LOCATION = "0025.jpg"              # PhotoCopy :P
image = cv2.imread(IMAGE_FILE_LOCATION)         # image read
coordinates = []

# Defining the event listener (callback function)
def shape_selection(event, x, y, flags, param):
    # making coordinates global
    global coordinates

    # Storing the (x1,y1) coordinates when left mouse button is pressed
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        coordinates = [(x, y)]

        # Storing the (x2,y2) coordinates when the left mouse button is released and make a rectangle on the selected region
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        coordinates.append((x, y))

        # Drawing a rectangle around the region of interest (roi)
        cv2.rectangle(image, coordinates[0], coordinates[1], (0, 0, 255), 1)
        cv2.imshow("image", image)

image_copy = image.copy()
cv2.namedWindow("image")
cv2.setMouseCallback("image", shape_selection)

# keep looping until the 'q' key is pressed
while True:
    # display the image and wait for a keypress
    cv2.imshow("image", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == 13:  # If 'enter' is pressed, apply OCR
        break

    if key == 27:  # Clear the selection when 'Esc' is pressed
        image = image_copy.copy()

if len(coordinates) == 2:
    image_roi = image_copy[coordinates[0][1]:coordinates[1][1],
                coordinates[0][0]:coordinates[1][0]]
    cv2.imshow("Selected Region of Interest - Press any key to proceed", image_roi)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

# closing all open windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image_roi)
print("The text in the selected region is as follows:")
print(text)
```

Comment: The code you shared is a mammoth, nobody has the patience to go through someone else's code this big. I suggest you create a sample code where there is no text,  but a rectangle with known coordinates which should be highlighted when selected. This way it is easier for you to actually solve the issue rather than worrying about a lot of stuff.

Comment: Reduced the code.. Please help me with the calf above :)

Answer (score 0):

This code can display the rectangle while the second click is not being done.

```
def shape_selection(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global coordinates
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        coordinates = [(x, y)]
        coordinates.append((x,y))
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if len(coordinates) == 2:
            coordinates.pop(1)
            coordinates.append((x,y))
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        coordinates.pop(1)
        coordinates.append((x,y))
    if len(coordinates) == 2:
        image[:] = image_copy[:]
        cv2.rectangle(image, coordinates[0], coordinates[1], (0, 0, 255), 1)
        cv2.imshow("image", image)
```